# SMB on a NIC with multiple IP in same subnet

Tags: windows, server-message-block, netsh

I have a Windows 2008 R2 server and set multiple IPs(same subnet) on a NIC. Now SMB service is binding on the lowest IP address as port 139, 455 are opened on it.

My question is, can I bind SMB to the IP I wanted but not to the default one?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Lower the interface metric on the adapter.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks for you reply. But I am talking multiple IPs on a single NIC scenario.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the default IP by re-ordering them in the registry:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\Tcpip\Parameters\Interfaces\{<ADAPTER GUID>}\IPAddress
```

[image]